# Mailchimp, DNS authenication not working

Tags: dns, mailchimp

Following Mailchimps instructions to setup custom DNS for Authenication

> Authenticate COGPS.org with MailChimp by modifying your domain's DNS records. These changes allow your campaigns to appear to come from COGPS.org, instead of from our servers. After you've made the required DNS changes, please wait 24-48 hours for the changes to propagate. Why should I do this?

```
DKIM: Create a CNAME record for k1._domainkey.COGPS.org with this value:
dkim.mcsv.net
SPF: Create a TXT record for COGPS.org with:
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
```

I've waited 48hr (really 4 days, that I've waited) but still receive an error.  Attached is are screenshots of their request, and my DNS records

```
NAME     TYPE    TTL    DATA    
@    TXT    1h    "v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all"

k1._domainkey    CNAME    1h    dkim.mcsv.net.
```

[What mail chimp has asked for in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUFN1.jpg)

[My Google domains custom DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCPzO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Those records are still not out on the DNS, I just checked with `dig` on Linux. I do not see anything wrong with how you have input them into Google.

Your Time to Live (TTL) value is four hours, so the data should be out there by now. At this point you should contact Google domains support.

There are two ways to check if the records are out there:

On linux commmand line:

```
dig COGPS.org ANY
```

On the Windows command line:

```
nslookup -query=txt COGPS.org
```

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. I'm never confident in my DNS settings when I'm setting up customs.. I'll follow up with google.